# Qt slots are not called in release mode and I blame QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

I have a problem with signal-slot mechanism, may be that it's actually a problem with `QSharedPointer` as smart pointers are new to me.

A little explanation of the context:
`TCPAssociation` is child class of `LANAssociation`. `TCPClient` is child class to `LANClient`. `LANClient` has protected `QSharedPointer<LANAssociation> connection` variable, `TCPClient` has private `QSharedPointer<TCPAssociation> conn`; both pointing to the same object being created in overriden pure virtual function shown below:

```
void TCPClient::startNewConnection(const QHostAddress &address)
{
    conn.clear();
    connection.clear();

    conn = QSharedPointer<TCPAssociation>(new TCPAssociation(address, port, QString("Client %1").arg(hostId())));
    Q_ASSERT(conn);

    Q_ASSERT(connect(conn.data(), &LANAssociation::started, this, &LANClient::assoc_started, Qt::UniqueConnection));

    connection = conn.staticCast<LANAssociation>();
    Q_ASSERT(connection);
    conn->start();
    //TCPAssociation::start() { doStuff(); emit started(); }
}
```

The code works on Windows 10 in debug mode just fine. In release mode on Linux, `LANClient::assoc_started` is never called.

Now I ran my server application (above function is from a client app) in release on Windows and I can see another slot not being called in release but working just fine in debug:

```
void ThreadController::init(ThreadWorker *worker)
{
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);

    Q_ASSERT(connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater, Qt::UniqueConnection));
    Q_ASSERT(connect(this, &ThreadController::operate, worker, &ThreadWorker::doWork, Qt::UniqueConnection));
    Q_ASSERT(connect(worker, &ThreadWorker::finished, this, &ThreadController::finished, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection));
    doConnects(worker);

    workerThread.start();
}
```

`*worker` points to child class of `ThreadWorker`. `ThreadWorker::doWork()` is virtual function. It was called in debug, not in release. I fixed it by making `doWork()` pure virtual - now it's called both in debug and release.

I have also problem with `QTcpSocket` and `QUdpSocket` objects not emitting `connected()` or `readyRead()`. Now I understand it's probably because I am using `QSharedPointer<QAbstractSocket>` to manage them, but:

1. why the difference between debug and release? how to do it properly?
2. Should I stop using inheritance or shared pointers?
3. why `TCPAssociation::started()` is not being emitted? `LANClient::assoc_started` is also not a virtual function.

Comment: I think you can try to call the connect method outside the Q_ASSERT macro. Depending on the configuration, it could be never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression inside the `Q_ASSERT` macro will not be evaluated in non-debug build configurations:

> `Q_ASSERT()` is useful for testing pre- and post-conditions during
>   development. It does nothing if `QT_NO_DEBUG` was defined during
>   compilation.
>
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_ASSERT